# Firebase Cloud Functions - How to call another function and return object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've created a callable function from my Angular component. My angular component calls the `createUser` function and successfully returns the `userRecord` value.

However, what I would like to do is call another cloud function called `createUserRecord`. I'm not overly familiar with promises and what needs to be returned where in this particular scenario.

Below are my two cloud functions. How would I go about calling `createUserRecord` upon the success of `createUser`?

```
export const createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    console.log('data = ', data);
    return admin.auth().createUser({
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
    }).then(function (userRecord) {
        return userRecord
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return error;
            console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
        });
});




export const createUserRecord = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user, context) => {
    const userRef = db.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    return userRef.set({
        email: user.displayName,
        createdAt: context.timestamp,
        nickname: 'bubba',
    })
});
```

**Update**

This is a version I produced where I merged the two functions together. This does produce the expected result of creating and account and then writing to firestore. However, it does feel a little 'off' due to the fact that it doesn't return a value to the client.

```
export const createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    console.log('data = ', data);
    return admin.auth().createUser({
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
    }).then(function (userRecord) {
        const userRef = db.doc(`users/${userRecord.uid}`);
        return userRef.set({
            email: data.email,
            name: data.name,
        })
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return error;
            console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
        });
});
```

**Angular Callable Function**

The `sanitizedMessage` console log will return undefined.

```
addUser() {

    const createUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createUser');

    const uniquePassword = this.afs.createId();

    createUser({
      email: this.userForm.value.email,
      password: uniquePassword,
      name: this.userForm.value.name,
    }).then((result) => {
      // Read result of the Cloud Function.
      var sanitizedMessage = result.data.text;
      console.log('sanitizedMessage = ', sanitizedMessage);
    }).catch((error) => {
      var code = error.code;
      var message = error.message;
      var details = error.details;
      console.log('error = ', error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: You should not call another Cloud Function from one Cloud Function. What is your exact User Requirement here? You want to create a record in the Realtime Database upon user creation? You could probably cover it in one Cloud Function.

Comment: Hey @RenaudTarnec - Essentially yes, but it's firestore in this instance. I have tried moving the `return userRef.set` method (from `createUserRecord`) into the `.then(function(userRecord)` of the `createUser` function. And that works. But it felt hacky. Would that actually be acceptable? Is there any particular reason not to chain functions in CF's?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec - I added an update to my code to explain the above comment.

Comment: I've just published an answer. Tell me how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a record in Firestore upon user creation you can very well do that within a unique Cloud Function. The following code will do the trick, making the assumption that you want to write to the `users` Firestore collection.

```
const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;

...
export const createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log('data = ', data);
  return admin
    .auth()
    .createUser({
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password
    })
    .then(userRecord => {
      return admin.firestore().collection('users')
        .doc(userRecord.uid)
        .set({
          email: userRecord.displayName,
          createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          nickname: 'bubba'
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
      return {
        result: 'Success'
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      //Look at the documentation for Callable Cloud Functions to adapt this part:
      //https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?authuser=0
    });
});
```

---

**"Is there any particular reason not to chain functions in CF's?" ?**

As explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/), "Cloud Functions can be associated with a specific trigger". You can "chain" Cloud Functions by creating the corresponding triggers, for example, creating a doc in Firestore in one CF (Callable Function for example), that would trigger another CF that respond to a Firestore trigger). **Having said that, in most cases you can probably cover a lot of needs in a unique Cloud Function, by chaining promises, instead of chaining Cloud Functions**.

Finally, I would not recommend to call an HTTP Cloud Function from within a Cloud Function because (IMHO) HTTP Cloud Functions are more designed to be called by an external consumer (I even don't know if this would work).

*It would be interesting to have Firebasers opinion on that!*

Comment: This works a treat. At least I was close with the second attempt. Thank you for such a fantastic response!